# How to use accesoryType in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

var restaurantIsVisited = [Bool](count: 21, repeatedValue: false)

var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "Thai Cafe"]

var restaurantImages = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafeloisl.jpg", "petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg", "posatelier.jpg", "bourkestreetbakery.jpg", "haighschocolate.jpg", "palominoespresso.jpg", "upstate.jpg", "traif.jpg", "grahamavenuemeats.jpg", "wafflewolf.jpg", "fiveleaves.jpg", "cafelore.jpg", "confessional.jpg", "barrafina.jpg", "donostia.jpg", "royaloak.jpg", "thaicafe.jpg"]

var restaurantLocations = ["Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "London", "London", "London", "London"]

var restaurantTypes = ["Coffee & Tea Shop", "Cafe", "Tea House", "Austrian / Causual Drink", "French", "Bakery", "Bakery", "Chocolate", "Cafe", "American / Seafood", "American", "American", "Breakfast & Brunch", "Coffee & Tea", "Coffee & Tea", "Latin American", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "British", "Thai"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.restaurantNames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurantLocations[indexPath.row]
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurantTypes[indexPath.row]

    // Circular image
    //   cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius =      cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    if restaurantIsVisited[indexPath.row] {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    } else {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let callActionHandler = { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavailable", message: "Sorry", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call" + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    let isVisitedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "I've been here", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in


        cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        self.restaurantIsVisited[indexPath.row] = true
    })
    optionMenu.addAction(isVisitedAction)
}
```

And Xcode says it does not have a member named "accessoryType"
Also it asks me to delete the question mark.

Here's the code for CustomTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

This is useless, the page asked me to add more details, I don't know what to add, so...
more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,more details, more details, more details, more details, more details, more details,

Comment: Where/how is `cell` defined? Please show a *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: and  `.CheckMark` should be `.Checkmark` ...

Comment: The *exact full error message* would also be helpful.

Comment: There are 2 Swift compiler errors, one is use of unresolved identifier "cell", another is Operand of postfix "?" should have optional type, type is "CustomTableViewCell"

Comment: In the initial version of your question you reported about an error message *"does not have a member named accessoryType"*. Now you have different error message? `cell?.accessoryType` should be `cell.accessoryType`, and in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, there is no `cell` variable, so of course it is undefined.

Comment: Actually in the initial version I deleted the ? mark. How do I define cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 2):

You can set accessory type by following way in swift.

```
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailDisclosureButton
```

May this help you.

Comment: This is not necessary and does not explain the error message. `cell.accessoryType = .None` compiles without problem (if cell really is a UITableViewCell).

Comment: This answer does not help or answer the question, as @MartinR already stated if it is a `UITableViewCell` that the OP uses, `.None` should work without the `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` prefix

Answer (score 0):

Since your syntax seems correct

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```

both seem to work in xCode Beta 6.3 using Swift 1.2

I can only figure that your cell is not properly initialized or not initialized as a UITableViewCell

Another type of cell in Swift is the `UICollectionViewCell`

```
var newCell = UICollectionViewCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))

newCell.accessoryType = UICollectionViewCellAccessorryType.Checkmark
```

The `UICollectionViewCell` does **not** have a `.accessoryType`
Using `UIColectionViewCellAccessoryType` is thus **not** possible.
Trying to access the `.accessoryType` at a `UICollectionViewCell` will result in the error `’UICollectionViewCell’ does not have a member named ‘accessoryType’`

This is an example if you use another type for your cell please verify that your cell type does have a `.accessoryType`

Try to see if you initialize as you ment to do it

Comment: Thanks! The cell is initialised as CustomTableViewCell, and there is an error saying "use of unresolved identifier 'cell'"

Comment: Could you please add the code of your CustomTableViewCell? (edit your question and add it in there)

Comment: Sorry but that is the code from your class, I requested the code from your CustomTableViewCell or did you create them using the storyboard?